# Как реализовать клиента при помощи JQuery или Angular 2+ или React?

Tags: java, jquery, веб-программирование, maven, spring-mvc

нужно создать простую HelloWorld веб-приложение на Java.

И в требование самым первом написано что:

1. Клиент должен быть реализован при помощи JQuery или Angular 2+ или React.

как это понять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бэкэнд должен быть на java, а фронтэнд на одном из указанных фреймворков. Как пример можно привести Rest API реализованное на spring, и фронт, который использует это API (отправляет REST запросы) для заполнения страницы данными.